# Exponential map and $\lim_{v,w \to 0} \frac{d(\exp(v),\exp(w))}{\|w-v\|}$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $v,w \in T_{p}M$. Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{v,w \to  0} \frac{d(\exp(v),\exp(w))}{\|w-v\|}=1$$

I completely don't know how to start. Thanks for any hint.

It is an exercise to lecture based on Milnor "Morse Theory", part II and III (the same as in do Carmo, chapters 3-5).

Comment: If you do not know where to start; at least explain how you stumbled on this problem? Your question needs more context.

Comment: It is an exercise to lecture based on Milnor "Morse Theory", part II and III (the same as in do Carmo, chapters 3-5).

Comment: You should add that to your question so that people will answer and not down vote your questions.

Comment: What do you know about the exponential map? What tools can you use?

Comment: Ony a bit (definiton and basic properties). But aby hint will be useful, because I van learn new metods.